# How do access file located in host from Jenkins installed in a local docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins

How can I connect my Jenkins in docker to my hosts local filesystem. I need to build a code snippet in my local filesystem from the Jenkins shell

Comment: The same way as you attach any other filesystem in Docker.  It's not specific to Jenkins (and therefore not a programming question).

Comment: How do i attach ? My first time with docker here .Try to be quite explicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear what do you mean by 'connect' but you can copy your code from docker via:

```
docker cp "$(docker ps -aqf name=your_image):/opt/path/to/your/file" .
```

ReBuild your docker image with the following (mind meta there):

```
FROM jenkins_image
COPY /your_project_dir/ /your_build_dir_injenkins/
```

Comment: I have a code written on my filesystem lets say /home/herlarbs/Desktop/Code.js  and I intend to build this code with Jenkins which currently resides in a container. So far i can't do that because Jenkins in the container does seem to have access to the Host filesystem

Comment: Ah, ok. Three ways to do this: via adding a shared volume or in docker compose or connect via SSH and copy your files

Comment: Thanks @AlexGera. You have been super awesome